# method "markedDatesFrom" in protocol "KalDataSource" not implemented ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, kal

I am trying to display the Kal (https://github.com/phaibin/Kal) calendar but I am getting some errors.

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Kal.h"


@interface CalendarViewController : UITableViewController <UIApplicationDelegate,KalDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet KalViewController *calendar;

@end
```

and my .m file:

```
#import "CalendarViewController.h"
#import "Kal.h"

@interface CalendarViewController ()


@end

@implementation CalendarViewController

@synthesize calendar = _calendar;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        _calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
        _calendar.delegate = self;
        _calendar.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_calendar.view];
        [_calendar loadView];
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Method 'presentingDatesFrom:to:delegate:' in protocol 'KalDataSource' not implemented.
Method 'markedDatesFrom:to:' in protocol 'KalDataSource' not implemented.
Method 'loadItemsFromDate:toDate:' in protocol 'KalDataSource' not implemented.
Method 'removeAllItems' in protocol 'KalDataSource' not implemented.
```

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? Thank you

Comment: have you gone through the documentation. Please look at this https://github.com/phaibin/Kal/blob/master/src/KalDataSource.h

Answer (score 1):

You have told the compiler that your CalendarViewController conforms to the KalDataSource protocol. That means you must implement all the required methods defined in that protocol. A quick look at the docs on github confirm that the protocol includes all the methods that you're getting warned about.

The solution is to implement those methods in your CalendarViewController class. I've never heard of the Kal class, so I don't know the details of what that means. It certainly means that you need to implement all the methods the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: You implement them in the .m file for your CalendarViewController class. Sounds like you need to take a step back and do some reading about Objective-C, and specifically about protocols. You might want to work through some tutorials that teach you these concepts.